# Why is lord hanuman worshipped in the form of stone, side faced & not in form of photo?

Tags: temple, hanuman, idols, story

In many temples, we see lord hanuman carved on a big stone covered with sindoor and Hanuman facing sided. Why there won't be his vigraha just like other gods? Is there any story behind his side posture?

*Could be a silly doubt, but i just like to know :p*